# As of / Starting in / Since / From (certain date)

Tags: phrases, expressions, expression-choice

I would like to know which of these phrases best fits in the following context:

As of / Starting in / Since / From 2015, the category "children and youth books" has replaced the previous category of "children books".

This is related to statistics on book publications, so it means that since that year onwards this category changed its name.

Specifically, I have the impression that the phrase "as of" conveys the idea that what is referred to will have an impact on the future. (e.g. "As of 2008 the visa facilitation agreement signed in 2007 came into force")

In this case, there is a change in the format of a report, but in reality, this is not going to have major consequences, it is simply the change in the name of an item in the report, to let the readers know that this item is the same which was called before with a slightly different name.

With this in mind, I would like to know if there is actually a difference in those phrases or are they interchangeable in the given context.

Answer (score 0):

If, as in your example, you are referring to a date in the past from which the change in classification has been made, then "Since 2015..." is fine. "Starting from..." is OK but what is wrong with "since"?

"As from..." conveys a change to take effect in the future. "As of 2015..." suggests some retrospective reclassification.

So, it all boils down to what it is that you wish the reader to understand. Was there a change in 2015? Or has there subsequently been a change applied retrospectively to records from 2015?

Comment: This is a statistical report which is published on an annual basis, so this change took place in the 2015 report and will be maintained in the future.  Apparently according to the information I have, what changes is just the name, so the category of previous years will still be comparable with the data indicated under this new name. Thank you very much for your comments.